# get disqus_thread_id from ethscan of token

Tags: python, html, api, web-scraping, ethereum

I am attempting to extract the Disqus thread ID of Ethereum contracts ([example](https://etherscan.io/token/0xae7ab96520de3a18e5e111b5eaab095312d7fe84#comments)) programmatically using Python, so that I can use the Disqus API to add comments to each contract. However, I am encountering an issue when using BeautifulSoup to extract the thread ID. Specifically, I am seeing an error message indicating that JavaScript and cookies must be enabled in order to continue. I have also attempted to use Selenium for this task, but have not been successful.